# baz_num_elts exercise from Software Foundations

Tags: coq

I'm at the following exercise in [Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/index.html):

```
(** **** Exercise: 2 stars (baz_num_elts) *)
(** Consider the following inductive definition: *)

Inductive baz : Type :=
   | x : baz -> baz
   | y : baz -> bool -> baz.

(** How _many_ elements does the type [baz] have? 
(* FILL IN HERE *)
[] *)
```

All of the answers I've seen on the Internet say that the answer is 2, and that the elements are x and y. If that's the case, then it's not clear to me what is meant by *elements*. There are certainly two constructors, but it's impossible to actually create a value of type *baz*.

It's impossible to create a value of type `baz` because `x` has type `baz -> baz`. `y` has type `baz -> bool -> baz`. In order to get a value of type `baz` we need to pass a value of type `baz` to either `x` or `y`. We can't get a value of type `baz` without already having a value of type `baz`.

So far I've been interpreting *elements* to mean *values*. So `(cons nat 1 nil)` and `(cons nat 1 (cons nat 2 nil))` would both be elements of type `list nat` and there would be an infinite number of elements of type `list nat`. There would be two elements of type `bool`, which are `true` and `false`. Under this interpretation, I would argue that there are zero elements of type `baz`.

Am I correct, or can someone explain what I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Sure. I've added a paragraph explaining why I think it's impossible to create a value of type `baz`.

Comment: Nice.  That's what I thought you were thinking.  Thank you, Twernmilt.  For what it's worth, I have the same reaction you do: I too would have expected the answer to be that there are zero elements of type `baz`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with you. There's a bijection between `baz` and `False`.

```
Definition injective : forall {t1 t2}, (t1 -> t2) -> Prop := fun t1 t2 f1 => forall x1 x2, f1 x1 = f1 x2 -> x1 = x2.

Definition surjective : forall {t1 t2}, (t1 -> t2) -> Prop := fun t1 t2 f1 => forall x1, exists x2, f1 x2 = x1.

Definition bijective : forall {t1 t2}, (t1 -> t2) -> Prop := fun t1 t2 f1 => injective f1 /\ surjective f1.

Inductive baz : Type :=
   | x : baz -> baz
   | y : baz -> bool -> baz.

Theorem baz_False : baz -> False. Proof. induction 1; firstorder. Qed.

Goal exists f1 : baz -> False, bijective f1.
Proof.
exists baz_False. unfold bijective, injective, surjective. firstorder.
assert (H2 := baz_False x1). firstorder.
assert (H2 := x1). firstorder.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the proof. makes  intuition quite clear